# Why does my audio stop playing when I switch tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, background

I'm using Chrome to listen to Youtube in the background (not on the Youtube app, but with Youtube being one of my Chrome tabs), and every time I switch tabs the audio stops playing.

This problem isn't isolated to audio playing on Youtube, but applies to any and all audio that I try to listen to in the background. This wasn't an issue before, and I'm not very tech savvy, so I'm not quite sure what the issue could be. I wonder if it was something that happened with an update.

I've gone to Chrome flags, but all of the options that have been recommended are not longer present where I'm looking:

(ex:#pause-background-tabs, #disable-background-video-track, etc.)

I've seen other questions like mine but they haven't been updated recently and I'm not really sure where to go from here. I've looked on multiple websites and some Reddit forums but a lot of it is either inconclusive or just plain confusing to me.

I'm on a Samsung tablet, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Did you read this article while looking around for solutions?
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/112920-enable-disable-tab-audio-muting-google-chrome.html

Comment: Does this happen in incognito mode?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is someone implemented by the website that wants you to play it in the app (and even then only with a premium subscription, in YouTube's case.

The best solution is to switch to a browser with the functionality to bypass that restriction. I use [**Vivaldi**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vivaldi.browser) and it has a setting for this:
[image]